# View Japanese text in emacs without X11

Tags: x11, emacs, fonts, locale

Is it possible to view Japanese (or more generally, international) fonts in emacs without running X11?

If yes, what is the process?

Nearly all the references I have found on the internet related to international fonts refer to the X11 system, but I am wondering if that is necessary.

I do not have X11 running because the computer is very old and I don't want to push it any more than is absolutely necessary. It is running OpenBSD 5.7.

When I try to view the Japanese text in emacs, only garbled text comes up regardless of the character-encoding I use to read the file with the `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` command. (OK, in fairness sometimes the hex codes are shown)

When I put the cursor over the character and type `C-u C-x =` to view character information, it says `preferred charset: japanese-jisx0208`, but the character is displayed as some strange international "a" with a couple accents on it.

Originally, only question marks were being displayed for the Japanese characters, but I changed that by setting  my locale to use `ja_JP.UTF-8` as the `LC_CTYPE` with `export LC_CTYPE=ja_JP.UTF-8`. The text now is mostly just various a's and e's with varying accents.

The output of `locale` is as follows:

```
$> locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_TIME="C"
...
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=
```

I also installed several japanese font packages:

```
$> pkg_info | grep ja
anthy-9100hp0       japanese input method
ibus-anthy-1.5.4    japnese input engine for ibus
ja-fonts-gnu-1.2p0  extra japanese fonts
ja-mplus-ttf-20060520p2    high quality japanese truetype fonts
ja-sazanami-ttf-20040629p2 japanese true type fonts
```

However, still no Japanese text is being displayed.

If anyone is interested, the sample Japanese document I am using is the __init__.py file from the [jctconv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jctconv/) python module.

Is there any way I can make this work without using X11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the OpenBSD console supports fonts for multibyte encodings.  In principle it might be possible to support them in relation to the recent `drm(4)` code, but I don't think anybody is working on that.  You might want to ask on an OpenBSD list for an authoritative answer.

Comment: Ok, so if it doesn't work in the base console, does that mean it wouldn't work in emacs also? Without x11 is everything limited to the font display limits of the base system?

Comment: @hilcharge How do you plan to run Emacs?

Comment: Through the base console.. good point. I think my understanding of how output and fonts are processed is lacking, but I will a deeper look at  `drm` to try to understand Thanks for the help!